# Can't start an old version of redmine (0.8.4)

Tags: ruby, installation, rake, redmine, rake-task

I have to bring back and old version of redmine, and make it work on windows 7. I have a mysql backup but first I want to have a working installation.

I installed ruby and rake

```
C:\>ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
C:\>gem --version
1.5.2
C:\>rake --version
rake, version 0.8.7
```

I found [here](https://es.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_redsf/downloads/redmine-0.8.4.tar.gz/) an installable, uncompressed it, and tried to follow [this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall?version=146)

I created the db (using mysql 5.5.12) and the redmine user.

Configured it on config/database.yml

When I try to exec `rake generate_session_store` I get:

```
C:\devel\redmine-test>rake generate_session_store
(in C:/devel/redmine-test)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate_session_store'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And then when I try to create the db I get:

```
C:\devel\redmine-test>set RAILS_ENV=production

C:\devel\redmine-test>rake db:migrate
(in C:/devel/redmine-test)
rake aborted!
#08S01Bad handshake

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Running with --trace effectively shows that it cannot connect to the db.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: can you actually post full trace errors?

Comment: Maybe you wanna try to install from https://github.com/redmine/redmine/releases/tag/0.8.7  not sure if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following install instructions for your specific version from here: https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/0.8.7/doc/INSTALL
which btw says tested with MySQL 5 so not sure if 5.5+ will work .

And get the source code as well from https://github.com/redmine/redmine/releases/tag/0.8.7

But also maybe try prepending your commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate

bundle exec rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

If you still have problems, please post full stack trace errors